# display: block for whole document by useing js

Tags: javascript, html

I created code in html, some elements on the page are hidden, only after pressing the button their content is shown, now at the end I want to create a button that will allow me to print my page, but before printing I would like whole content to be shown, how can I globally for all html show whole content, html structure look like that

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="pl">
        ALL LINKS ETC
        <script type="text/javascript" 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <header>
                HEADER CONTENT
            </header>
            <section class="sekcja">
<h2>SECTION_PART_1</h2>
                    <div class="works-h">
  <p1>titte1</p1><i onclick="myFunction(this)" data-Type="test1" class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i><br>
  <div class="describe test1" style="display: none;">kontent1</div>
  <br><br>
  <p1>tittle2</p1><i onclick="myFunction(this)" data-Type="test2" class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i><br>
  <div class="describe test2" style="display: none;">kontent2</div>
</div>
        
                    <h2>SECTION_PART_2</h2>
                        <div class="skills-h">
  <div id="skills1" data-chartType="a" class="skill active">a</div>
  <div id="skills2" data-chartType="b" class="skill">b</div>
  <div id="skills3" data-chartType="it" class="skill">it</div>
</div>
<div class="charts">
  <canvas class="chart a" id="myChart1" width="400" height="100" style="background: white;"></canvas>
  <canvas class="chart b" style="display: none; background: red;" id="myChart2" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas class="chart it" style="display: none; background: blue;" id="myChart3" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
            </section>
    
            <footer><button onclick="displayAndPrint()">Click to Print</button></footer>
        </div>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and i got 2 scripts that are responsible for showing/hidding content
first one for first part of section

```
   function myFunction(element){
      
      d = document.evaluate("following-sibling::div", element, null,
      XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue
      
      if (d.style.display == "none"){
        d.style.display = "block";
        element.className = "fas fa-angle-double-up";
      }else{
        d.style.display = "none";
        element.className = "fas fa-angle-double-down";
      }
    }
```

and the second one:

```
var div_elements = document.querySelectorAll(".skill");
var item_elements = document.querySelectorAll(".chart");
for (var i = 0; i < div_elements.length; i++) {
  div_elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    div_elements.forEach(function(div) {
      div.classList.remove("active");
    });
    this.classList.add("active");
    var div_value = this.getAttribute("data-chartType");
    item_elements.forEach(function(item) {
      item.style.display = "none";
    });
    if (div_value == "a") {
      document.querySelector("." + div_value).style.display = "block";
    } else if (div_value == "b") {
      document.querySelector("." + div_value).style.display = "block";
    } else if (div_value == "it") {
      document.querySelector("." + div_value).style.display = "block";
    } else {
      console.log("");
    }
  });
};
```

thx print button is at the end, in footer, I thought that code line like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("main").style.display = "block";
```

will help, but no, thx for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You have to iterate through it:

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName("main") 
for(const elem of elems) elem.style.display = "block";
```

Although using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is the more logical solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".main").forEach(elem => elem.style.display = "block");
```

Comment: hymm 
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName("main") 
for(const elem of elems) elem.style.display = "block";

not giveing any efect, do i have to change some more code?

Comment: @PatrykKobyłka It should work. Are there any errors?

Comment: no, everything is fine
function display() {
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName("main") 
for(const elem of elems) elem.style.display = "block";
console.log("Hello world!");
}

may it be coz of css?

Comment: for example that function:
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("main");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   elements[i].style.display = "block";
}

is changeing backgroud color but i dont rewrite display  value

Comment: ok i made it by useing this function:
function display() {
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("describe");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
   elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
window.print()
}

"describe" and chart" are div classes which contain hidden coontent, they are inside "main" div, i thought  line 
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("main") 
will work for every div inside "main" div